# How to disable Windows 10 window resize behavior after snapping?

Tags: windows-10, window, window-manager

I like Windows' snapping features, for the most part. I have trouble with one aspect of the feature, which resizes a window back to its previous size after snapping, if you move the window. I would rather keep the window at the snapped size.

Follow these steps to see what I mean:

1. Open a new window

   - Note the size of the window at this point
2. Snap it to the side of the screen (Win + LeftArrow)
3. Resize the window to be shorter
4. Move the window to another spot

You will observe after step 4 that the window returns to the size it was in step 1. Windows remembers that size and recalls it when you move the window. Is there a way to have Windows keep the size I set via snap/resize instead of the previous size?

Comment: While there is certainly nothing wrong with your request, everyone on my team actually *prefers* the default behavior.  Please keep in mind that after your "step 4," you have essentially unsnapped the window.  As a result, it returns to its default size prior to being snapped to the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got tired of similar behaviors and so I turned off the Windows Aero effects and started using [WindowPad](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/19990-windowpad-window-moving-tool/) instead.  It is a heavily customized AutoHotKey script that you can run as a standalone EXE with an INI file to configure it to your tastes.

When you do the snap in Step 2, WindowPad is actually moving and sizing the window to that location, rather than "snapping" it, so you can then make some adjustments to the size or position and it won't come "unsnapped".  There is a newer version of this called WindowPadX, but honestly I've never tried it because this does all that I need it to.

Below is my INI file, since I tweaked it a little from the default install, but it sounds like that's how you might want it.  The **[exclude]** sections can probably be ignored.  I think they are just there to keep WindowPad from messing with DisplayFusion, which I also have installed.

```
[Options]
TitleMatchMode=2

[Hotkeys]

[Hotkeys: Active Window (Numpad)]
*Numpad1 = WPM, -1, +1,  0.5, 0.5
*Numpad2 = WPM,  0, +1,  1.0, 0.5
*Numpad3 = WPM, +1, +1,  0.5, 0.5
*Numpad4 = WPM, -1,  0,  0.5, 1.0
*Numpad5 = WPM,  0,  0,  0.5, 1.0
*Numpad6 = WPM, +1,  0,  0.5, 1.0
*Numpad7 = WPM, -1, -1,  0.5, 0.5
*Numpad8 = WPM,  0, -1,  1.0, 0.5
*Numpad9 = WPM, +1, -1,  0.5, 0.5
*NumpadAdd = MaximizeToggle
*NumpadEnter = WindowScreenMove, Next
*NumpadDiv = GatherWindows, 1
*NumpadMult = GatherWindows, 2

[Hotkeys: Previous Window (Numpad)]
*Numpad1 = WPM, -1, +1,  0.5, 0.5,  P
*Numpad2 = WPM,  0, +1,  1.0, 0.5,  P
*Numpad3 = WPM, +1, +1,  0.5, 0.5,  P
*Numpad4 = WPM, -1,  0,  0.5, 1.0,  P
*Numpad5 = WPM,  0,  0,  0.5, 1.0,  P
*Numpad6 = WPM, +1,  0,  0.5, 1.0,  P
*Numpad7 = WPM, -1, -1,  0.5, 0.5,  P
*Numpad8 = WPM,  0, -1,  1.0, 0.5,  P
*Numpad9 = WPM, +1, -1,  0.5, 0.5,  P
*NumpadAdd = MaximizeToggle, P
*NumpadEnter = WindowScreenMove, Next, P
*NumpadDiv = GatherWindows, 1
*NumpadMult = GatherWindows, 2

[Exclude Windows]
Process=displayfusion.exe

[Gather: Exclude Windows]
Window=ahk_class SideBar_AppBarWindow
Window=ahk_class SideBar_HTMLHostWindow
Window=ahk_class BasicWindow

[Gather: Exclude Processes]
Process=displayfusion.exe
```